# load the DIV tag based on delay given by user run time - angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a range slider by which user can set the delay time to load the certain div tag. After setting the delay time, user will click the toggle switch if it is enabled then after certain delay time div will load. Please help me on this. How to implement this in angularjs.

**Here is my code of slider**:

```html
<span class="font-weight-bold indigo-text mr-2 mt-1">{{min}}</span>
<form class="range-field w-25">
  <input class="border-0" type="range" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" ng-model="interval" />
</form>
<span class="font-weight-bold indigo-text ml-2 mt-1">{{max}}</span>
</div>
<p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Selected range is: <b>{{min}}s - {{interval}}s</b></small></p>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Now, user can click the toggle switch:**toggle switch code**

```html
<div class="btn-switch" ng-class="{'btn-switch--on':toggle.switch}" ng-model="toggle.switch" ng-click="toggle.switch = !toggle.switch"></div>
<div class="btn-switch-circle" ng-class="{'btn-switch-circle--on':toggle.switch}" ng-model="toggle.switch" ng-click="!toggle.switch = toggle.switch"></div>
```

If switch is enabled then the DIV tag will load after given delay time(**eg.delay- 139s)**

Please help me on this.